# Authorization process is not working Properly In Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I have a problem like this. I am creating an angular application with node. In there I have created a token based login system and I store token and user data in the local storage.

This is my service file.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient , HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {User} from "./user";


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  user: any;
  authToken: any;
  // readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/user';
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user: User){
      let headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
      return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/register', user, {headers: headers});

  }

  loginUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/user/login', user, {headers: headers});

  }

  storeData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem("tokenid", token);
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  getProfile(){


    this.fetchToken();

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Authorization',this.authToken);
    console.log(headers.append('Authorization',this.authToken));
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.get("http://localhost:3000/user/profile",{headers:headers})

  }

  fetchToken(){

    const token = localStorage.getItem("tokenid");
    this.authToken = token;

  }



}
```

This is my particular web component to where that I load data with the token.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService} from '../../shared/user.service';
import {Router} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-adminpannel',
  templateUrl: './adminpannel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adminpannel.component.css'],
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class AdminpannelComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private userService: UserService,private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.getProfile().subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res)
    })
  }

}
```

This is my backend file where I check whether this user is valid or not.

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var  User  = require('../models/user');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../db');
const passport =require('passport');


router.post("/register",function (req,res) {
    const newUser = new User({
        username: req.body.username,
        name:  req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
    });

    User.saveUser(newUser, function (err,user) {
        if(!err){
            res.json({state:true, msg:"data Inserted"});
        }

        else{
            res.json({state:false, msg:"data Is Not Inserted"});
        }
    });
});

router.post("/login", function (req, res) {
    const email=req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;

    User.findByEmail(email, function (err, user) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!user){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"No user found"});
        }

        if(user) {
            User.passwordCheck(password, user.password, function (err, match) {
                if (err) {
                    res.json({state: false, msg: "your password is incorrect"});
                }

                if (match) {
                    const token = jwt.sign(user, config.secret, {expiresIn: 86400 * 3});
                    res.json(
                        {
                            state: true,
                            token: "JWT " + token,
                            user: {
                                id: user._id,
                                name: user.name,
                                username: user.username,
                                email: user.email

                            }
                        }
                    )

                }

                else {
                    res.json({state: false, msg: "password does not match"});
                }
            });

        }

    });
});

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false}), function(req, res) {
        res.json({user:req.user});
    }
);


module.exports = router;
```

This is my passport Jwt Strategy configuration file.

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
    ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const config = require('../db');
const User = require('../models/user');

const opts = {};
opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeader();
opts.secretOrKey = config.secret ;

module.exports = function (passport) {

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {


        User.findUserbyId({_id: jwt_payload._doc._id}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if (user) {
                done(null, user);
            } else {
                done(null, false);

            }
        });
    }))
}
```

When I check this with postman it gives the correct output but when I tried to load admin panel. It always gives me an error like this.

```
zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:3000/user/profile 401 (Unauthorized)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2969
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:297
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:401
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:255
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1114
(anonymous) @ zone.js:3001
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1394
(anonymous) @ http.js:2364
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
subscribeToResult @ subscribeToResult.js:23
MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub @ mergeMap.js:138
MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext @ mergeMap.js:135
MergeMapSubscriber._next @ mergeMap.js:118
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
ScalarObservable._subscribe @ ScalarObservable.js:51
Observable._trySubscribe @ Observable.js:172
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:160
MergeMapOperator.call @ mergeMap.js:92
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
FilterOperator.call @ filter.js:61
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
MapOperator.call @ map.js:57
Observable.subscribe @ Observable.js:157
AdminpannelComponent.ngOnInit @ adminpannel.component.ts:16
checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline @ core.js:12411
checkAndUpdateNodeInline @ core.js:13935
checkAndUpdateNode @ core.js:13878
debugCheckAndUpdateNode @ core.js:14771
debugCheckDirectivesFn @ core.js:14712
(anonymous) @ AdminpannelComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1
debugUpdateDirectives @ core.js:14697
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:13844
callViewAction @ core.js:14195
execEmbeddedViewsAction @ core.js:14153
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:13845
callViewAction @ core.js:14195
execComponentViewsAction @ core.js:14127
checkAndUpdateView @ core.js:13850
callWithDebugContext @ core.js:15098
debugCheckAndUpdateView @ core.js:14635
ViewRef_.detectChanges @ core.js:11619
(anonymous) @ core.js:5918
ApplicationRef.tick @ core.js:5918
(anonymous) @ core.js:5751
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
onInvoke @ core.js:4760
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:387
Zone.run @ zone.js:138
NgZone.run @ core.js:4577
next @ core.js:5751
schedulerFn @ core.js:4342
SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:243
SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:190
Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:131
Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:95
Subject.next @ Subject.js:56
EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:4322
checkStable @ core.js:4725
onHasTask @ core.js:4773
ZoneDelegate.hasTask @ zone.js:441
ZoneDelegate._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:461
Zone._updateTaskCount @ zone.js:285
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:205
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:595
ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
error (async)
customScheduleGlobal @ zone.js:1666
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:407
Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:232
Zone.scheduleEventTask @ zone.js:258
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1831
desc.set @ zone.js:1244
ResourceLoaderImpl.get @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:548
DirectiveNormalizer._fetch @ compiler.js:3145
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:3341
DirectiveNormalizer._loadMissingExternalStylesheets @ compiler.js:3340
DirectiveNormalizer._normalizeTemplateMetadata @ compiler.js:3252
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:3180
then @ compiler.js:475
DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate @ compiler.js:3180
CompileMetadataResolver.loadDirectiveMetadata @ compiler.js:14914
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:34420
(anonymous) @ compiler.js:34419
JitCompiler._loadModules @ compiler.js:34416
JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ compiler.js:34374
JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ compiler.js:34268
CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync @ platform-browser-dynamic.js:239
PlatformRef.bootstrapModule @ core.js:5578
(anonymous) @ main.ts:11
./src/main.ts @ main.bundle.js:193
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
0 @ main.bundle.js:201
__webpack_require__ @ inline.bundle.js:55
webpackJsonpCallback @ inline.bundle.js:26
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
core.js:1449 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 401, statusText: "Unauthorized", url: "http://localhost:3000/user/profile", ok: false, …}
```

Can someone help me to send this token correctly to the backend? Thank You!

Comment: What Passport JWT Strategy do you use? Bearer?

Comment: I update the question with the strategy.

Comment: Did you already inspect the 'User Profile Get Request' in Chrome DevTools and compared the Authorization Header with the one from the Postman Request. My feeling is that something with the Scheme might be wrong - (https://github.com/themikenicholson/passport-jwt/issues/72)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your `getProfile()` method. `HttpHeaders` is **immutable**. You might wanna write:

1. `headers = headers.append(...);` because `.append` returns a clone.
2. Or you can put your headers object in the constructor of `HttpHeaders` on `headers = new HttpHeaders(<object_goes_here>)`